# Can I use set operators on sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Is it valid to use set operators with sequences?

Let say I have a set of elements $O$, and I want to define a sequence of elements $P$, made up exclusively of elements of $O$, is the following notation valid?

$P = (a_0, a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \subseteq O$

Similarly, lets say I then want to create a mapping of an element $a$ in the sequence $P$ to its index $i$, is it valid to say that this mapping is defined as:

$Q(a) = i$ where $a = a_i \in P$

I know the above example is a bit trivial, but I need to use it in more complex definitions, so I need to make sure it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is standard notation and could be difficult to read correctly as a result.

It would be clearer to say $P = (a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n) \text{ where } a_i \in O \text{ for each } i$.

Then you can just say $Q(a_i) = i$. Then it's clear that if $a = a_i$ then (assuming $Q$ is well-defined) $Q(a) = Q(a_i) = i$.

If $Q$ is only defined on the elements of $O$ in the sequence $P$ you can just define that to be its domain.

> $Q$ is a function on $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$....

or something like that.

If all your sequences are going to be finite, it might also be clearer to talk about them as tuples.

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree its clearer. Is there a way to say that an element is in a sequence though?

Comment: It should be clear that an element like a_i is in the sequence if you've been consistent and clear with your notation. Otherwise you could state it in words. Another option is to have a named indexing set $I$, so your sequence is $a_i$ where $i \in I$, and indexing set. Then you can say "$a_i$ for some $i \in I$" and it should be clear that this is an element of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to be care when viewing sequences as sets. Two sequences can consist of the same elements but not be the same. For example, $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$. Both consist only of $\{-1,1\}$, but are not the same sequence.

Comment: Yes. I don't have the issue though in my case, I just want to state whether an element is in a sequence or not. I am not comparing sequences.

Comment: Got it. Using the set notation can be done I suppose, but it's generally avoided for the above stated reason.